# Result returned from SQL query is always 0

Tags: c, sqlite

The function below is supposed to check whether or not a specific entry exists in a table. If the entry exists, it returns a 1. If it doesn't, it returns a 0. However, it only returns a 0.

Table used: `Database( ID int Primary Key, char(100) Place, char(100) Room )`, all are NOT NULL. **All of the queries shown in the results below are in Database.**

```
//database is already open at this point
int searchForRoom(sqlite3 *db, char *place, char *room){
    int result = 1;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    //Create SQL statement
    char * sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
            "Select EXISTS(Select * From Database "
            "Where Place = '%q' and Room = '%q');"
                , place, room);

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_ROW) {
        printf("ERROR 1 reading data: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    //only this line of code does not output the correct result
    result = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);

    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        printf("ERROR 2 reading data: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    printf("%s, %s evals to %d\n", place, room, result);

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    return result;
}
```

The result:

```
place1, venue1 evals to 0
place2, venue2 evals to 0
place3, venue3 evals to 0
```

Comment: You must check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. (But this isn't the problem you're looking for.)

Comment: The obvious answer is that a row with these values indeed does not exist.

Comment: @CL. I've checked it beforehand. The columns produced to stmt was 1 and the type shown when evaluated with sqlite3_column_type() was 1 (integer flag). Also, the entries shown were in the table Database.

Comment: Yes, EXISTS returns a boolean value, which is an integer 0 or 1 in SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why or how, but it seems that restarting my computer actually solved the problem. The function now works perfectly fine. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

```
        "Select EXISTS(Select * From Database "
```

The EXISTS query returns either 0 (when no such row(s) exist) or 1 (when they do). It returned 0, so no such rows existed.

Comment: He says that the rows do exist.

Comment: @Barmar well, then either a) they actually don't, or b) something else makes the query think they don't. Returning of 0 in that case means no such rows exist